# how auto-rotate atop logs

Tags: linux, rhel, performance, top, atop

we can see that atop logs are created on each day
and that take a lot of space

```
ls -l /var/log/atop/
total 1634632
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 127992086 Aug 30 01:49 atop_20180829
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 262277153 Aug 31 00:00 atop_20180830
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 321592670 Sep  1 00:00 atop_20180831
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 330041977 Sep  2 00:00 atop_20180901
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 269040388 Sep  3 00:00 atop_20180902
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 274807097 Sep  4 00:00 atop_20180903
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  85426960 Sep  4 06:03 atop_20180904
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 Sep  4 06:03 daily.log
```

how to limit the atop log for example to only 5 logs ( 5 last days )

Comment: this isnt logical , wht atop not include conf for this?

Comment: Please provide `ls /etc/logrotate.d`. There might be a file `atop` in there which then governs how logrotate treats the log files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In RH/CentOS `atop` is not being regulated by `logrotate`.

In `/usr/share/atop/atop.daily` there is an example script to deal with `atop` log file rotation.

The script as a find line deleting logs older than 28 days as in:

```
# delete logfiles older than four weeks
# start a child shell that activates another child shell in
# the background to avoid a zombie
#
( (sleep 3; find $LOGPATH -name 'atop_*' -mtime +28 -exec rm {} \;)& )
```

You can copy that script to `/etc/cron.daily` and change the number of days to 5.

```
( (sleep 3; find $LOGPATH -name 'atop_*' -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;)& )
```

Dealing with daily files can also be a bit inconvenient. Using the above script, if you do not intend in doing a pure daily rotation, you can also edit `/etc/sysconfig/atop` and change the duration, for instance for 10 minutes, as in:

```
INTERVAL=600
```

**As an alternative**, if you do want to keep rotating it daily, you can create a `logrotate` file at `/etc/logrotate.d/atop` as in:

```
/var/log/atop/atop_20[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] {
    missingok
    daily
    nodateext
    rotate 5
    ifempty
    nocreate
    postrotate
      /usr/bin/find /var/log/atop/ -maxdepth 1 -mount -name atop_20\[0-9\]\[0-9\]\[0-9\]\[0-9\]\[0-9\]\[0-9\]\* -mtime +40 -exec /bin/rm {} \;
    endscript
    }
```

If you are doing the `logrotate` version, you need to keep the daily files, and do not change the INTERVAL parameter.

Comment: regrading the second part , sorry but not understand to which value to change the INTERVAL=? , in order to keep the log for 5 days

Comment: @yael Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution after reading and spending somes times with atop.

```
#!/bin/sh

LOGOPTS=""                              # default options
LOGINTERVAL=600                         # default interval in seconds
LOGGENERATIONS=28                       # default number of days
LOGPATH=/var/log/atop                   # default log location

# allow administrator to overrule the variables
# defined above
#
DEFAULTSFILE=/etc/sysconfig/atop                # possibility to overrule vars

if [ -e "$DEFAULTSFILE" ]
then
        . "$DEFAULTSFILE"

        # validate overruled variables
        # (LOGOPTS and LOGINTERVAL are implicitly by atop)
        #
        case "$LOGGENERATIONS" in
            ''|*[!0-9]*)
                echo non-numerical value for LOGGENERATIONS >&2
                exit 1;;
        esac
fi

CURDAY=`date +%Y%m%d`
BINPATH=/usr/bin
PIDFILE=/var/run/atop.pid

# verify if atop still runs for daily logging
#
if [ -e "$PIDFILE" ] && ps -p `cat "$PIDFILE"` | grep 'atop$' > /dev/null
then
        kill -USR2 `cat "$PIDFILE"`       # final sample and terminate

        CNT=0

        while ps -p `cat "$PIDFILE"` > /dev/null
        do
                CNT=$((CNT + 1))

                if [ $CNT -gt 5 ]
                then
                        break;
                fi

                sleep 1
        done

        rm "$PIDFILE"
fi

# delete logfiles older than N days (configurable)
# start a child shell that activates another child shell in
# the background to avoid a zombie
#
( (sleep 3; find "$LOGPATH" -name 'atop_*' -mtime +"$LOGGENERATIONS" -exec rm {} \;)& )

# activate atop with an interval of S seconds (configurable),
# replacing the current shell
#
exec gzip $LOGPATH/atop_$[CURDAY -1]
echo $$ > $PIDFILE
exec systemctl restart atop > "$LOGPATH/daily.log" 2>&1
```

Add this in /etc/crond.daily/atop.daily

Hope this help